# Pointer on Struct used in function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have some problems in C with pointers and structs:
I have 2 entities of the struct `Signal` and the pointer `activeSignal` to store one of the entities. Now, I want to use this "stored" entity in my function `printParameters()` to print the values of my struct. Unfortunately, my microcontroller-display prints some hieroglyphics instead of my value. I have to admit that I am not completely looking through pointer-arithmetic...

```
struct SigParameter {
  char *name;
  int value;
};

struct Signal {
  struct SigParameter signalchar;
};

int main(void) {
  struct Signal s1;
  struct Signal s2;
  s1.signalchar.name = "Sinus";
  s2.signalchar.name = "Rect";
  struct Signal *activeSignal = &s1;

  printParameters(activeSignal);
}

void printParameters(struct Signal *s) {
  lcdPrintf(0,11,9,"%s", s->signalchar.name);
}
```

Comment: I'm by no means a C expert, but this does seem right to me. Does it work correctly if you replace `s->signalchar.name` with simply `"Hello"`?

Comment: Humour me for a moment and try `printf("%s", s->signalchar.name);`. Code looks fine to me; apart from the fact that `name` should be a `const char*` if you're assigning literals to it.

Comment: Are you sure `lcdPrintf` works fine? Have you tried `lcdPrintf(0,11,9,"%s", "Sinus");`? Add semicolon in your struct.

Comment: lcdPrintf() works fine. i can print "sinus" easily. the semicolon was also not the problem :/

Comment: Have you considered adding function prototype at the top? `void printParameters(struct Signal *s);` after the struct definitions or perhaps defining function `printParameters` before `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, there are some minor mistakes in your code. I believe those are typos.

1. No forward declaration for `printParameters()`.
2. in your `main()` , function called is `printParameter()` which should be `printParameters()`.
3. missing semicolon after `struct SigParameter signalchar`

However, i don't see a,logic for using the `struct Signal *activeSignal = &s1;` if you simply want to print the value.

You can check the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct SigParameter {
 char *name;
 int value;
};

 struct Signal {
 struct SigParameter signalchar;
};

void printParameters(struct Signal s);

int main(void) {
 struct Signal s1;
 struct Signal s2;
 s1.signalchar.name = "Sinus";
 s2.signalchar.name = "Rect";

 printParameters(s2);
    return 0;
}

void printParameters(struct Signal s) {
    printf("%s\n", s.signalchar.name);
}
```

I have used simple `printf()` instead of your `lcdPrintf()`, but it works fine.

Output:

> [sourav@broadsword temp]$ ./a.out
>
> Rect

Comment: well, this was just a extract of my code. if i use printParameters(s2) it works fine. but i want to implement it a bit more dynamic, so i was trying it with that pointer on the struct

Comment: @JulianHerbel how dynamic? like changing the value and/or memory allocation? other than that, for any type of operation, above code _should_ work fine.

Comment: @JulianHerbel 1) to modify the value, simply pass `&s1` or `&s2`. 2) beware, the string literals are usually `read-only`.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct SigParameter signalchar
```

In this semicolon is not placed. May be it is a mistake.

Then While assigning the value to the character pointer you have to allocate the memory for that pointer. Otherwise it will store the value in the register memory.

```
s1.signalchar.name = "Sinus";
s2.signalchar.name = "Rect";
```

You can allocate the memory for that pointer variable and do the work in that.

Then you are calling the function

```
   printParameter(activeSignal);
```

But the function is,

```
   printParameters(activeSignal);
```

Comment: well, i see no problem in `s1.signalchar.name = "Sinus";`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int value;
}SignalParameters;

typedef struct{
    SignalParameters signalchar;
}Signal;
void printSignal(Signal* s);
int main(void) {
    Signal s;
    s.signalchar.name = "Sinus";
    printSignal(&s);
    return 0;
}

printSignal(Signal * s) {
    printf("%s", s->signalchar.name);
}
```

This works for me on gcc-4.8.1, so there's nothing wrong with your pointer arithmetics. It is probably related to the clib of your Microcontroller. To give more usefull answers we will need to know which Microcontroller you're using and we need the definition of lcdPrintf.
By the way, typedefs safe a lot of typing in C ;-).